# Displaying full list of items in a PHP session shopping cart

Tags: php, cart

Having some problems with a shopping cart I have set up in that it doesn't display each item in the cart, instead it displays the correct number of items but repeats the first item added to the cart each time.

I get what's wrong, but just not sure how to go about fixing it... basically currently I am only performing ONE query on the recordset, and that is what is being displayed. In my basic knowledge of PHP I'd say that I need to do a query for EACH item in the cart (which is only a maximum of 6 so never going to be large).

The numbers in the cart are the same as the ship_id numbers from the database.... therefore I was thinking can I just put something like:

```
   $sql = "SELECT $ship_id, $ship_name, image
    FROM $ship_infomation
    WHERE $ship_id =  $cartId;";
```

...inside the foreach loop, but this breaks the thing

Could someone point in the best direction for guiding me to solve my little problem.

Many thanks

**Shopping Cart Display:**

```
 <?php 
    $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
  if (!$cart) {echo "<div class='dialogue_box_inside_info_request'>
 <div class='dialogue_box_image'>
    <img src='images/basket_empty_dialogue.png' width='618' height='264' />
    </div>
</div>";}
  else
  {

      $array = explode(',', $_SESSION['cart']);

  echo "<table width='835' border = '0'>";
  foreach($array as $cartId) {
  $ship_name = $row_ships['ship_name'];
  $ship_image = $row_ships['image'];
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td width='110' height='58' class='table_text'><img src='images/ships/$ship_image'width='83' height='53' /> </td>";
  echo "<td width='620' height='58' class='table_text'>$ship_name</td>";
  echo "<td width='35' height='58' class='table_text'><a href='cart.php?action=delete&ship_id=$cartId'><img src='images/trash.png' width='31' height='42' /></a></td>";
  echo "<td height='58'>$cartId</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  } 
  echo "</table>";

  }
   ?>
```

**Recordset placed at top of code**

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_ships, $ships);
$query_ships = "SELECT ship_id, ship_name, image FROM ship_infomation";
$ships = mysql_query($query_ships, $ships) or die(mysql_error());
$row_ships = mysql_fetch_assoc($ships);
$totalRows_ships = mysql_num_rows($ships);
?>
```

Comment: `session_start();` is nowhere to be found, or have you left that out? This is required in ALL pages at the top, since you are using sessions.

Comment: it's not on the cart page no, but would this fix my entire problem? where should I put it?

Comment: I'll bet it will, theoretically. As I stated `session_start();` MUST be included as the first line and in ALL pages used, and located at the very top, underneath your opening `<?php` tag. Try that first and keep me posted.

Comment: it doesn't make any difference at all Fred - I have two versions of the page for testing one with my bodged WHERE $ship_id =  $cartId;"; inside the foreach, and one without - the one with doesn't show anything, the one without has the repeating ship :-(

Comment: Try doing a `var_dump($ship_id)` and `var_dump($cartId)`

Comment: think I know why it hasn't made a difference... the code I have included is a php file which is 'php-included' on a main page, which DOES have session_start() on (sorry real newby here). What would I do with those var_dumps.... sorry if I'm asking too much, but a bit stuck

Comment: I'm curious, you don't have a `$` for `image` in `$query_ships = "SELECT ship_id, ship_name, image FROM ship_infomation";`

Comment: Place the var_dumps anywhere you want, it will `echo` out the results.

Comment: sorry - worked it out using an echo.... results are NULL 
string(1) "1" so ship_id has no value then?

Comment: Why would he use a variable for a table attribute?

Comment: @user2406993 There doesn't seem to have a value set for `ship_id`, no.

Comment: that's what I'm trying to do I think Fred, link the cartId to ship_id... am I going about it the wrong way do you think?

Comment: @user2406993 When it comes to linking, there I won't be able to help. Have you tried `Ander's` answer below?

Answer (score 0):

```
$row_ships = mysql_fetch_assoc($ships);
```

This row must be placed inside your loop.

An example of how you could organize it all. It's all with my own variable names so you will have to do a little bit of replacing.
In the session you put an array of all the items in the cart. You do not have to store this as a string separated by commas or similar like you do now. Just do `$_SESSION['cart'] = array()`

To add a product you use the push function.
`$_SESSION['cart'].push($itemid);`

To remove a product from the cart you have to itterate through the array to find the right entry and unset that. I will not do that code for you right now. Just pointing you in the right direction.

If you store the id of the products/items in the session you may create a query like this:

```
<table>
<?php
$where = implode(', ', $_SESSION['cart']);
$rec = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE id IN ($where)");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rec)) {
    // Output whatever you need.
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><img src='images/ships/$row['image']</td>";
    echo "<td>$row['name']</td>";
    echo "</tr>"
}
?>
</table>
```

Also you should consider switching to the mysqli library instead since the mysql functions are deprectated. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Thanks for your time in looking at this Anders, this is exaclt where I am struggling. I have put your code inside the loop, and I get 'Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied resource is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/elbowroo/public_html/ship_image/information_request_form_ship_info.php on line 106' - I'm sorry but this is literally my first sql project and I'm self taught, so no idea about what to use and what not to use

Comment: Okey. To do this as simple as possible. Does your session contain a cart id, or does it contain a list of product id's? Essentially, what are your link between the session and the database?

Comment: the session contains cartId, which is just a list of numbers (I think an Array. This is in no way linked to the database. The link between the two  is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. (the cartId number has an equivalent ship_id) and that is I think what I want to do... you'll notice in my cart code I'm currently echoing $cartId, but this is just for testing so I know that the items are being addedd to the cart

Comment: @user2406993 If you're using a form in conjunction with your code, just thought of something. If you have a set of `radio` buttons or `checkmarks`, then you might be missing the array brackets, as in `[]`. That's all I can think of at this point.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that You can see only the first item is that You are fetching only the first line with mysql_fetch_assoc() function. And as stated in other answer, You are not limiting the number of rows fetched from database.

Your assumption is right, and should work, but avoid using queries inside a loop.

You could move the `explode(',', $_SESSION['cart']);` up where the query is and the resulting array of numbers give inside the WHERE clause, so You will get only the products, that You have in the cart.

```
$cartIdArray = explode(',', $_SESSION['cart']);
/* here You should check that all are integers, or apply mysql_real_escape_string() */
$query_ships = "SELECT ship_id, ship_name, image
  FROM ship_infomation
  WHERE ship_id IN(" .  implode(", ", $cartIdArray) . ")";
```

And You can delete the `$row_ships = mysql_fetch_assoc($ships);` line. And in the output section instead of the foreach, use

```
while($row_ships = mysql_fetch_assoc($ships))
{
  $ship_name = $row_ships['ship_name'];
  $ship_image = $row_ships['image'];
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td width='110' height='58' class='table_text'><img src='images/ships/$ship_image'width='83' height='53' /> </td>";
  echo "<td width='620' height='58' class='table_text'>$ship_name</td>";
  echo "<td width='35' height='58' class='table_text'><a href='cart.php?action=delete&ship_id={$row_ships['ship_id']}'><img src='images/trash.png' width='31' height='42' /></a></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: thanks for your thorough answer Jan, can I just check.... the 'move the explode' section, I'm not entire sure where I should be moving that too. thank you

Comment: I asume, that the $_SESSION['cart'] is a string of comma separated values which You are exploding before the echo section. You should do that before querying the database. So You have to put the first section of code from my answer before the `$ships = mysql_query(...` line

Comment: thanks, just trying now - and yes I thnk you're right they are CSV strings

Comment: I'm just getting this now... Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied resource is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/elbowroo/public_html/ship_image/information_request_form_ship_info.php on line 106 Perhaps my fiddling with the code has wrecked it :-( help!

Comment: I've just edited the answer, You were using dollar signs inside the query. These are column and table names, not php properties. I've copied it from Your post and didn't see it. Copy please the updated query

Comment: Thanks for your time Jan, it's all broken now nothing is showing so I'm going to have to start again I think